# Why would librviz (in Python) only sometimes read the config file?

Tags: python, rviz, roslaunch, librviz, groovy-turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using librviz in a GUI using python (PyQt/PySide) I started with the librviz tutorial (docs.ros.org/hydro/api/rviz_python_tutorial/html/) and was able to use my own config files to show the panels and views that I want.  The problem is that it is extremely sporadic.

I have tried:

- alternating config files
- downloading the tutorial and testing my config file with the tutorial script
- using the tutorial config file (raw.githubusercontent.com/ros-visualization/visualization_tutorials/hydro-devel/rviz_python_tutorial/config.myviz) with my script
- using the tutorial config file with the original tutorial code.
- restarting the computer
- Loading the config files into rviz (this works)

When it doesn't work, it looks something like this (tutorial script + tutorial config file):
Broken image- i.imgur.com/j1rlQsf.png)

I note that it probably isn't reading the config file properly, because one of the first functions in the tutorial pulls from the file and changes the title, and it does not manage to even do that.

When it is working (my code + my config):
Working image: (i.imgur.com/nN7vKkF.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182475/why-would-librviz-(in-python)-only-sometimes-read-the-config-file?/) by [Xiuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19247/xiuda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was an issue with it not finding the correct path to the config.rviz file. I realized it when it worked in a terminal window that was in the package directory but not in one where it was not.  Adding a launchfile that specifies the location of the file as a parameter fixes this problem.

```
        import rospkg
```

and in the init for the class we have

```
    reader = rviz.YamlConfigReader()
    config = rviz.Config()

# We use rospack to find the filepath for the package using rviz.
    rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
    package_path = rospack.get_path('demo')
#Now you can grab this filepath from either roslaunch and using the launch file or just rosrun with the file in a config folder
    config_file = rospy.get_param('demo/rviz_config', package_path + "/config/myConfig.rviz")
    reader.readFile( config, config_file )
    self.frame.load( config )
```

---

Originally posted by [Xiuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19247/xiuda/) with karma: 36 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DyuAdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/77223/dyuadi/) on 2021-07-27**:
Hi, I'm having the same problem except with c++, what exactly is `self.frame` in your working code? Could you post the line where you assign that value?